# Share a common package between server and client

Tags: typescript

I want to have the following project setup:
Three top-level folders client, common and server. All of them is a separate package with its own package.json and node_modules folder.

For the example below I use this structure:

```
- common
  - node_modules
  - package.json
  - entities.ts

- server
  - node_modules
  - package.json
  - app.ts
  - tsconfig.json
```

And I try to run tsc in the server folder

Files that should be used by both client and server will be in the common folder and I would like to use ES6 module syntax for importing them from both server and client like `import {MyModel} from 'common/entities';`

The problem is that I can't figure out how to setup typescript to understand this setup.

I have used `npm link` to make common appear as a normal node_module in the server but the above import generates the error `Cannot find module 'common/entities'`. I tried adding `"moduleResolution": "node"` to `compilerOptions` without result.

Is there possible to get typescript to understand this setup or is there a setup that is preffered to this?

Comment: You asked this long time ago - any progress in finding the answer since then?

Comment: Basically though a bit more advance than I would like. You will have to build common separately to .d.ts and .js files and use npm link (or, yarn workspaces for maximum comfort) to use common as any other node module

Answer (score 0):

> Is there possible to get typescript to understand this setup or is there a setup that is preffered to this?

I tend to just go with a *single* tsconfig.json with a single `node_modules`. And then am just careful not to use stuff outside `common` and `client` from the frontend.

Its still better than what it would be without the safety of TypeScript.

Comment: Whit a single node_modules it's hard to build a nice artefact as it requires tree shaking to remove the modules that aren't used in the client or else it would produce a massive output. I would like to solve this in a good way or else I will resort to plain JS. My view is that tests should provide the saftey, types is just for developer comfort.